# How to use p2 artifacts in standard maven project

Tags: maven, tycho, p2

I have standard maven project with standard dependency type:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ogp</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.pt.core.messages.api</artifactId>
        <version>${coreVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The issue is that above dependency is of type p2.
Adding p2 repository in "repositories" section and using tycho does not help.
How can I use p2 dependencies in standard maven projects (with jar packaging type, not eclipse-plugin type)?

Comment: when you say p2, you mean a different repository?

Comment: The artifact from the dependency above is in the p2 repository (such repositories is used for updating Eclipse components, for example).
Just want to understand how to use artifacts from that repositories in standard maven projects (not Eclipse plugins)

Comment: add the repo to your settings.xml

Comment: repositories are added but tycho and maven are ignoring them

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating simple osgi bundle that will build first, and produce big jar with all the OSGI bundles unpacked as described here: [Use dependencies from Eclipse p2 repository in a regular Maven build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682028/use-dependencies-from-eclipse-p2-repository-in-a-regular-maven-build).
That jar will be used in standard maven projects.