# Adding dependency using Maven to eclipse-pdt in pom.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, eclipse-pdt

I am trying to import the parser from [Eclipse PDT](https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) in a project using Maven, however, I cannot find how to do it.

I added the following in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.php</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.php.core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.php</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.php.core.parser</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

However, these packages are not located on https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, like for example [Eclipse JDT](https://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/) ([org.eclipse.jdt](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt))

Is there a maven repository from where these packages (org.eclipse.php.core, org.eclipse.php.core.parser) can be downloaded using Maven, together with all their dependencies?

Comment: Can you use 5.1.0 instead?

Comment: 5.2.0 would be better, however, 5.1.0 can also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since newer versions are not available in public Maven repositories, the following two ways to get the Eclipse PDT PHP parser JAR via Maven remain:

- From following [Eclipse **p2 repository** via Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6682028/6505250): **`http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/5.2-nightly/`**
- Get the `plugins/org.eclipse.php.core.parser_{version}.jar` JAR from an Eclipse PDT installation and [include the **local JAR** in your `pom.xml` file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4955635/6505250)